# How to "pull" specific data from an html file and crunch the data

Tags: html, ruby, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am new to programming and I have a question about how to pull specific information from a page on a website, crunch the data to check and see if it meets certain parameters, and store urls of the pages that meet the parameters.

The problem is this:

-There is a website with several articles.
-I would like to be able to make a list of urls of articles on the site that contain fewer than x number of words.

I don't need help with the coding or anything because I am new to this and this is essentially a self-exercise for me to learn to program.

I just have questions as how to go about this. I know HTML and minimal Ruby and that's the extent of my knowledge.

I just don't know how to "pull" the data from a webpage. :S What would I use to pull HTML? What do I do with the HTML after I pull it? Convert it to Ruby? If so, how?

Comment: tagged question as ruby. What you're talking is an HTML parser. I don't know ruby, but someone should be along to answer pretty soon.

Comment: Would Ruby and HTML knowledge be sufficient for this project given than I will have to do webscraping?

Comment: oh most definitely, that's all you need. There are lots of libraries for doing exactly this

Comment: +1 to you for asking what is the right way to go about it, instead of assuming regex would be the right thing. Regex is seldom a good mix with HTML or XML, but a good parser is always the right way to go, whether it's Ruby, Python, Perl or Java. And, yes, Ruby and Nokogiri make a great web scraping solution. Check out `Mechanize` when you need to walk sites and `sanitize` or `loofah` when you need to whitelist/blacklist tags and clean pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri' 
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))
doc.xpath(//a).each {|node| p a.text}
```

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is a library to parse HTML/XML documents in Ruby. Have a look on the webpage for more information on how to install/use it.

Comment: I love the Windows install instructions: "Luckily for you, building on Windows is so difficult that we’ve done it for you"